# TypeError: Expected data to be int, Sequence or Mapping, but got method pytorch lighning

Tags: pytorch-lightning

I have this LightningDataModule:

```
class MTmetricDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
 def __init__(self, df):
  super().__init__()
  self.reference = df['reference'].astype(str)
  self.translation = df['translation'].astype(str)
  self.z_score = df['avg-score']
  self.z_score = np.array(self.z_score)


def setup(self, stage=None):
 self.reference_train, self.reference_test, self.translation_train, self.translation_test, 
 self.z_score_train, self.z_score_test = train_test_split(self.reference, self.translation, 
 self.z_score, test_size=0.2)
 self.reference_test, self.reference_dev, self.translation_test, self.translation_dev, 
 self.z_score_test, self.z_score_dev = train_test_split(self.reference_test, 
 self.translation_test, self.z_score_test, test_size=0.1)


 self.df_train = pd.DataFrame()
 self.df_train['reference'] = self.reference_train
 self.df_train['translation'] = self.translation_train
 self.df_train['z_score'] = self.z_score_train
 self.train = self.df_train.to_dict("records")

 self.df_dev = pd.DataFrame()
 self.df_dev['reference'] = self.reference_dev
 self.df_dev['translation'] = self.translation_dev
 self.df_dev['z_score'] = self.z_score_dev
 self.dev = self.df_dev.to_dict("records")

 self.df_test = pd.DataFrame()
 self.df_test['reference'] = self.reference_test
 self.df_test['translation'] = self.translation_test
 self.df_test['z_score'] = self.z_score_test
 self.test = self.df_test.to_dict("records")


def train_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
 return DataLoader(
   dataset=self.train,
   batch_size=batch_size
 )

def val_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
 return DataLoader(
   dataset=self.dev,
   batch_size=1
 )

def test_dataloader(self) -> DataLoader:
 return DataLoader(
   dataset=self.test,
   batch_size=1
 )
```

That I then just feed into my LightningModule

```
data = MTmetricDataModule(df)
model = MTmetric()
trainer = Trainer(gpus=1, progress_bar_refresh_rate=20, max_epochs=2) 
trainer.fit(model, data)
```

But I am currently getting the error "RuntimeError: Input, output and indices must be on the current device".

I am currently running it in Colab with a GPU instance and nothing seems to make it work.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It means some of your data is on gpu and some is using cpu. Pleae transfer the whole data on same device and run it again.
Currently, you data loader is loaded on cpu and for 'trainer' you are using GPU might be the error.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.to(device)` might be useful. `device = cuda()` or `cpu()`

[This solution](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/best-way-to-move-parameters-to-gpu/72441/3) on Pytorch_Forums will be helpful.